# Dynamically defining a Object#initialize for a Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

In my code base, I have a bunch of objects that all adhere to the same interface, which consists of something like this:

```
class MyTestClass
  def self.perform(foo, bar)
    new(foo, bar).perform
  end

  def initialize(foo, bar)
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
  end

  def perform
    # DO SOMETHING AND CHANGE THE WORLD
  end
end
```

The differentiating factor between the classes is the *arity* of the `self.perform` and `initialize`, plus the body of the `#perform` class.

So, I'd like to be able to create an `ActiveSupport::Concern` (or just a regular `Module` if that would work better) which allowed me to do something like this:

```
class MyTestClass
  inputs :foo, :bar
end
```

which would then use some meta-programming to define `self.perform` and `initialize` of the above methods whose airty would depend on the airty specified by the `self.inputs` method.

Here is what I have so far:

```
module Commandable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def inputs(*args)
      @inputs = args
      class_eval %(
        class << self
          def perform(#{args.join(',')})
            new(#{args.join(',')}).perform
          end
        end

        def initialize(#{args.join(',')})
          args.each do |arg|
            instance_variable_set(@#{arg.to_s}) = arg.to_s
          end
        end
      )

      @inputs
    end
  end
end
```

This seems to get the *arity* of the methods correct, but I'm having a tough time figuring out how to handle the body of the `#initialize` methods.

Can anybody help me figure out a way that I can successfully meta-program the body of `#initialize` so it behaves like the example I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close! `instance_variable_set` takes two arguments, first is the instance variable and second is the value you want to set it to. You also need to get the value of the variable, which you can do using `send`.

```
instance_variable_set(@#{arg.to_s}, send(arg.to_s))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this as body for `#initialize`:

```
#{args}.each { |arg| instance_variable_set("@\#{arg}", arg) }
```

---

However, I wouldn't string eval it. It usually leads to evil things. That said, here is an implementation which gives an incorrect `Foo.method(:perform).arity`, but still behaves as you would expect:

```
module Commandable
  def inputs(*arguments)
    define_method(:initialize) do |*parameters|
      unless arguments.size == parameters.size
        raise ArgumentError, "wrong number of arguments (given #{parameters.size}, expected #{arguments.size})"
      end

      arguments.zip(parameters).each do |argument, parameter|
        instance_variable_set("@#{argument}", parameter)
      end
    end

    define_singleton_method(:perform) do |*parameters|
      unless arguments.size == parameters.size
        raise ArgumentError, "wrong number of arguments (given #{parameters.size}, expected #{arguments.size})"
      end

      new(*parameters).perform
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  extend Commandable
  inputs :foo, :bar

  def perform
    [@foo, @bar]
  end
end

Foo.perform 1, 2 # => [1, 2]
```